# Cannot connect to some websites from one laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I'm at my wit's end. Here is the situation.

I have three devices connecting to my WiFi router: two laptops and one Galaxy S2 tablet.

On the first laptop, I can access any web site, no issues at all.
On the second laptop, I can only access a few web sites, but not others.
On the tablet, I can only access a few web sites, but not others.

I've verified that it's not the ISP. I connected the second laptop directly
to the DSL modem and all was well. When I hard-wired the second laptop into the
WiFi router, same problem ... not able to access many web sites.

I thought the problem was with the WiFi router, but that can't be the case since
the first laptop works just fine when connected to the same router.

Can anyone explain to me why my first laptop works like a dream while my second
laptop and tablet both cannot access the same web sites as my first laptop while
connect over the same WiFi?

Tried shutting down and restarting the router, modem, and laptop, tried ipconfig /release, ipconfig /renew, ipconfig /flushdns ... none had any effect.

I really don't understand how different devices connecting to the SAME WiFi
router cannot access the same web sites.

Please help and thanks

Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your second laptop's OS is Windows. You should start a Command Prompt and check your connectivity using `ping 8.8.8.8 -t`.
If everything is smooth aka no packet loss, you should go further with debugging: check DNS settings on your browser and laptop. To do so you should first check the `C:\Windows\system32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file and see if there are any suspect records there. If not, you should reinstall your browser (or better yet: install a new one).
If none of this solve your issue you can manually enter a DNS server in your network adapter settings: 8.8.8.8 - Google's public DNS.

Comment: I tried all of that and still the same results.  On the laptop with the issues, here is a summary of what works and doesn't work, using Facebook and Yahoo as test web sites.  1. Connected over Wifi - Facebook works, Yahoo does not.  2. Hardwired to the router - Facebook works, Yahoo does not.  3.  Hardwired to the DSL modem - Facebook works, Yahoo works.  In all three instances, I am able to ping yahoo.com, but only when I am hardwired to the DSL modem is the web page returned.  On my other laptop, no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, so the problem now appears to be solved.  This is what I did.  Log onto the router, go to WAN settings, and change the MTU from 1492 to 576, save, reboot.  Then change the MTU back to 1492, save, reboot.  Now everything works as it should again.  I think perhaps it's time for a new router.  This is 2nd or 3rd day where it has been giving me problems and each time had to find a funky workaround in order to get it back to functional.  Thanks for your help!